# Java command prompt

Tags: java, compiler-construction, command, javac, prompt

I am trying to compile a program in java using the command prompt.  My program runs fine in eclipse, however, when I try to compile it in command prompt I received an error message.  Any help and direction would be much appreciated.

This is my main program that calls the class Loop.
    import logic.Loop;

```
public class Triton {

    Loop loop = new Loop();

    loop.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 600));
    loop.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE));
    loop.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE));

    JFrame frame = new JFrame(TITLE);
    frame.add(loop);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    environment = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    device = environment.getDefaultScreenDevice();
    frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
```

This is my Loop class

```
package logic;

public class Loop extends Canvas implements Runnable{
    rest of my code goes here...
}
```

When I compile the code in command prompt I am in the directory containing the main class and I try to compile using javac Triton.java  This is the error I get.

Triton.java:9: error: package logic does not exist
import logic.Loop;

Triton.java:20: error: cannot dind symbol
            Loop loop = new Loop();

symbol:  class Loop
 location: class Triton
Trion.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
            Loop loop = new Loop();
  sybmol: class Loop
  location: class Triton
3 errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Loop was imported via eclipse and isn't in the build itself.  Therefore it can't reference it outside of eclipse.  Essentially, your compiler is compiling Triton without pulling the Loop dependency.

Try `javac Loop.java Triton.java`

Comment: How would I go abouts importing it?

Comment: I cut of my imports above triton which has import logic.Loop

Comment: I tried that however, it still says can't find loop.  I however, just read somethig that says I have to compile it from the parent directory.  In this case source. It did compile this time. However, when I call java Trident I get a Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Trident(wrong name: main/Trident)...  any ideas?

Comment: I mis-typed, I thought you named it Trident, you named it Triton.  Another simple solution would be javac *.java.  * is a wildcard that'll take any text in for it.  So it looks for all files in that directory that ends with .java.  If your java files are in subdirectories, then try `javac **/*.java`

Comment: When working on projects with more than one class, I'd create a makefile to make life easier in the long run.

http://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/~newhall/unixhelp/howto_makefiles.html

Scroll to Java